# Change responsive webpages into fixed width webpages using inspect element

Tags: html, css, web, inspect-element

I've been wondering if there is a way to change responsive webpages online into fixed width webpages through inspect element. For example, in most websites and webpages when you resize the window all the text shifts to fit in the smaller or larger window space which gets sort of annoying  if you're using split screen because the format gets all messed up. [All the text is shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAUxL.png) [Original Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haJIp.png)

My desired outcome would be instead of the text moving when you resize your window, the text just gets cut off and you can use a scroll bar to access these cut off parts. This is very similar to how google docs works.[Text isn't shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt5uq.png) [Original Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY6vt.png)

I've done some experimenting on this, and from what I've gathered (All of the modifications I did were in the css):

- Putting in a min-width, max-width, width, height, max-height, and min-height (using both percentages and px) doesn't really work for most webpages
- Using resize:none doesn't work
- Using nowrap just makes the text on these websites go off the screen on one line
- Using inline block hasn't given me any noticeable changes
- Using overflow hasn't given me any luck either
- Messing with the margins doesn't work
- Deleting all the original body CSS doesn't do much

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Set the width and height for `body` as a fixed length with `overflow: auto`. However, this wouldn't stop media queries.

Comment: Does meta viewport help?